# php adding SSL certificate

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I have a problem.

My website is running an SSL on the checkout page. This is the current message I get.

> The page at 'https://jonathanmichael.co.uk/checkout/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at
>   'http://jonathanmichael.co.uk/': this content should also be submitted
>   over HTTPS.

```
<form action="http://jonathanmichael.co.uk/" method="get" id="adminbarsearch"><input class="adminbar-input" name="s" id="adminbar-search" type="text" value="" maxlength="150"><input type="submit" class="adminbar-button" value="Search"></form>
```

My question is how do I fix this? I'm using Wordpress, I have found this code which I think links to it.

**searchform.php**

```
<!-- Start SearchForm -->
<form method="get" class="searchform" role="search" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="s" type="text" id="s" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search', THB_THEME_NAME ); ?>" class="small-12">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<!-- End SearchForm -->
```

I have zero knowledge of PHP for help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does changing the call to `<?php echo home_url('', 'https'); ?>` work?

Answer (score 1):

Easy.  Just explicitly change the form action to:

```
<form action="https://jonathanmichael.co.uk/checkout/"
```

Also, please use **$_POST** for your form.
**$_GET** should not be used for anything that is supposed to be secure.

```
<form action="https://jonathanmichael.co.uk/checkout/" method="POST" id="adminbarsearch">
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, where exactly am I likely to find this? In a html document or something?

Comment: The issue seems to be the search forms on the checkout page are posting to regular `http` so the browsers are complaining.  The form in the post is not the checkout form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `$scheme` parameter to the call to `home_url()`

This will let you generate the link with the `https:\\` prefix.

See the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url

```
<!-- Start SearchForm -->
<form method="get" class="searchform" role="search" action="<?php echo home_url($scheme = https); ?>/">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="s" type="text" id="s" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search', THB_THEME_NAME ); ?>" class="small-12">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<!-- End SearchForm -->
```

Comment: Hi, That didn't seem to work. I now have two more errors, the error is on my website at the checkout. I was wondering if you could provide some help please? If you add something to your cart and proceed to checkout - https://jonathanmichael.co.uk/checkout/ Kind regards.

Comment: The page at 'https://jonathanmichael.co.uk/checkout/' was loaded over HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at 'http://jonathanmichael.co.uk/https/': this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.

(index):550 The page at 'https://jonathanmichael.co.uk/checkout/' was loaded over HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at 'http://jonathanmichael.co.uk/': this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.

Comment: Try using `home_url( $path = '/', $scheme = https );`  Maybe you need to specify both parameters.

Comment: Updated:  The page at 'https://jonathanmichael.co.uk/checkout/' was loaded over HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at 'http://jonathanmichael.co.uk//': this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.

(index):547 The page at 'https://jonathanmichael.co.uk/checkout/' was loaded over HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at 'http://jonathanmichael.co.uk/': this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.

:(

Comment: Looks like it should be `home_url( $path = '', $scheme = 'https');` to get you a proper URL. And hopefully quotes around https will actually get a secure URL.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I'm now getting this...

 The page at 'https://jonathanmichael.co.uk/checkout/' was loaded over HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at 'http://jonathanmichael.co.uk/': this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.

jonathanmichael.co.uk/:553 The page at 'https://jonathanmichael.co.uk/checkout/' was loaded over HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at 'http://jonathanmichael.co.uk/': this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.

Comment: At this point I'm not sure... based on the Wordpress documentation it should be generating https URLs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70337/discussion-between-jonathan-saich-and-michael-murray).